# Acquire CSRF token using apache http-components

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

Hi I am using Apache http-components in Java for invoking REST calls. When I attempt a POST on a form, the request is not going through. I figured that is because I am not setting the CSRF token. Could you guys please clarify how I can get the csrf token using apache httpcomponents in a Java Rest Client?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look into the response headers of your `GET` to the page containing the form.